# Using a ::before pseudo element on UL to create a time line representation

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I would like to achieve a visual layout of a story line using `li` elements inside a `ul`, something that would look like this:

```
li-element1
 .
 .
li-element2
 .
 .
li-element3
```

I am using the `::before` pseudo element to add a line through the whole ul element, but it is visible on top of the `li` elements, which i do not want to happen. How can I have the line to hidden behind the `li`s and only be visible between the margin gaps? i have unsuccessfully tried the Z-index property already. here is a [link to a pen](http://codepen.io/valecarlos/pen/VPGaad) with my current code.

```css
.container ul{
  position: relative;
}
.container ul::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
.container ul li{
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Update**

In the original question, I was oblivious to the fact that the bullets in `li` elements, are not actually part of the `li` element itself and hence are not actually affected by any background-color set to them. Now with this in mind and implementing the answers suggested, combining the use of z-index, background-color, margins and paddings and, additionally setting the ul `list-style-type: none` I have updated the code to:

```css
.container ul{
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  position: relative;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.container ul::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 16px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
.container ul li{
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 0px 0px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>• First</li>
    <li>• Second</li>
    <li>• Third</li>
    <li>• Fourth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i have tried to set the position to relative on the `li` elements so i can actually use the z-index on them and then set different values on them and the `ul::before` class but it doesn't seem to move the elements on top of the line, which is what i was expecting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a white background, padding and relative positioning to hide part of the timeline with each item:

```css
.container ul{
  position: relative;
}
.container ul::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
.container ul li {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: -20px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 40px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the list icons, and replace them with pseudo-elements: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qRMZyy

```
.container ul{
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
}
.container ul::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  z-index:100;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
.container ul li {
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
.container ul li:before {
  content: "";
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  z-index: 0;
  left: -20px;
}
```

Comment: I think that's actually a good idea, however, running the code, the two elements are still overlapping

Comment: Ah, I misread the question, I just switched the `z-index` of the elements.

Answer (score 2):

`z-index` should work fine.  You have two options: negative `z-indez` on the line or positive `z-index` on the `<li>`s.

## Negative z-index:

```css
.container ul{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.container ul::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
  z-index: -1;
}
.container ul li{
  margin: 15px;
}

body {background: #888;}
.container ul::before {border-color: #000;}
.container ul li {color: #FFF;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

## Positive z-index:

```css
.container ul{
  position: relative;
}
.container ul::before{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  border: 1px dashed blue;
}
.container ul li{
  margin: 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

body {background: #888;}
.container ul::before {border-color: #000;}
.container ul li {color: #FFF;}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: by running the code snippet, the vertical line still seems to be at the same Z-position as the `li` elements. By setting the margin on the `li`s to 0px you still can see the line overlapping with the letters

Comment: @randomguy04 I don't think we're seeing the same thing.  I've zoomed my browser in and set the margin to `-2px`. It's clearly behind the text: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbEQ8.png.  What browser, browser version, and OS are you using?

Comment: @JosephMarikle Here's what Firefox in Windows 7 shows: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQXH3.jpg

Comment: @TylerH Looks correct to me.  I've updated my answer to have higher contrast, but abl may be correct in his answer in thinking OP wants to cover the path with the background color rather than just have the text on top of it.  We'll see what OP has to say.  Yours appears to follow that thought too. OP needs a better demonstration of what he/she is after here.

Comment: you´re right Joseph, i have misformulated my question and i will update it properly, thing is i didn't take into account that the li bullets do not actually take part of the li element itself, hence i was expecting a different behaviour, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to put the borders on pseudo-element children of the `<li>` elements instead of the `<ul>` element. This is probably not the best method, though.

```css
.container ul{
  position: relative;
}
.container ul li{
  margin: 2px;
}
.container ul li::after, .container ul li::before {
  content:" ";
  border-left: 1px dashed blue;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: -12px;
  top: 0;
  height: 12px;
}
.container ul li:last-child::after, .container ul li:first-child::before {
  content:"";
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul>
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: In Chrome, the dots for every item after the first one are shifted left and up, for distance of about two lengths.

Comment: @Dragomok Classic webkit... thanks for letting me know